# Parcel an array object of costum objects

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class `Tok` that has some variables (int, int, String ... )

I also have a class `TokList` that extends `ArrayList<Tok>`.

In my `MainActivity.java` I created an `TokList` instance ( `TokList tl = ...` ), and filled it with some `Toks`.
I want to pass this `tl` variable to another activity initiated from `MainActivity.java`

question is: What class must implement `Parcelable` (and have the required methods) and what will the `intent.putExtra()` argument look like in the `MainActivity.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Tok` class must implement `Parcelable` and when you're writing to parcel, for your `TokList` you should do this :

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    ...
    out.writeSerializable(yourList);
}
```